# MySQL Count Since

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder how the following could be solved with a mysql query, but don't really know how to proceed

i have 3 tables (i will try to keep them simple)

```
          post

       id  | content 
           |
       1   | bla, bla..
```

---

```
          comment                          |                votes
                                           |
id | post_id | comment | date              |        id | comment_id | date 
                                           |           |            |
5  |    1    |  derp   | 2012-07-06        |        1  |     5      | 2012-07-07
6  |    1    |  nherp  | 2012-07-07        |        2  |     5      | 2012-07-08
7  |    1    |  yada   | 2012-07-08        |        3  |     5      | 2012-07-09
8  |    1    |  lala   | 2012-07-09        |        4  |     6      | 2012-07-10
                                           |        5  |     6      | 2012-07-11    
                                           |        6  |     7      | 2012-07-12
                                           |        7  |     8      | 2012-07-13
                                           |
```

they are tied to each other in this way

comment.post_id  is a fk to post.id

votes.comment_id is a fk to comment.id

What i'm trying to discover is how many votes have been given to **the entire post** after each comment. Or in other words, how many votes have been given to entire post after the submission of each comment.
So, for this example case i presented, the result i was expecting would be the following table

```
                                      result

                  id | post_id | comment | date        | votes_after_submission
                     |         |         |             | 
                  5  |    1    |  derp   | 2012-07-06  |          7
                  6  |    1    |  nherp  | 2012-07-07  |          6
                  7  |    1    |  yada   | 2012-07-08  |          5
                  8  |    1    |  lala   | 2012-07-09  |          4
```

This is giving my brain a knot, i tried using the CASE keyword in the COUNT statement, but couldn´t actually make it work for this problem, can anyone give me some clues, or point me in the right direction or maybe just throw me some google keywords to search for as i didn´t find anything on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question and example result correctly, try this:

```
SELECT C.id,C.post_id,C.comment,C.date, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM votes AS V 
        WHERE V.date > C.date 
          AND V.comment_id IN (SELECT id FROM comment AS C2 
                               WHERE C2.post_id=C.post_id)) AS votes_after_submission
FROM comment AS C
ORDER BY C.post_id, C.date
```

I'm not sure it's the most efficient, but it works.

Comment: Hi, comment.id is tied to comment_id, i ended up not showing it in the solution, but they are tied.

Comment: @roimatola, Can you then show how they are related.  I guess none of us understand.  Please amend your question so that we better understand what you are trying.

Comment: i edited the question to try to make the relationships clearer. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @roimatola,  I edited my answer which produces the results you have listed.  (I tried it.)  If this is not what you expect, please provide more information.

Comment: Thanks, its definitely closer, but i believe this is counting all the votes ever done, and is not binding to the votes given to a specific post. I guess i have to try to be even clearer in the question, sorry.

Comment: @roimatola, I reworked the answer to take into account the post_id.  Note that it will return all post_id's but sorted.  You can alway add a `WHERE` filter before `ORDER BY` to choose a specific post_id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
select 
comment.id,
post_id, comment,
date,
count(votes.id) as no_of_vote
from comment
inner join votes on (comment.id=votes.comment_id)
group by comment.id
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, i should have given more enphase on the part that i need all the votes given to entire post, and this gives me the count of votes for each specific comment.

Comment: just to see if i can make a bit clearer now, i am trying to get all the votes given in the entire post after each specific comment insertion date

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select comment.id, comment.post_id, comment.date, count(1) Votes
    from comments, votes
    where comments.id = votes.comment_id and votes.date >= comments.date
    group by comment.id, comment.post_id, comment.date,
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, however, this doesn´t give the expected results, i believe that because of the "comments.id = votes.comment_id" part, the count results in the count of the votes given to that specific comment, and i was going for all the votes given to entire post.

Comment: just to try to make it clearer, all the votes given in the entire post after each specific comment insertion date